# How to downgrade from kitkat to jelly bean?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

May I know how to downgrade from android 4.4.2 kitkat to jelly bean? There are many problems on my galaxy note 10.1 after upgraded to kitkat. Please help me~ Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you took a backup of your ROM before updating, then you can restore the backup. Alternatively, if your phone is rooted then you can download a stock Jelly Bean ROM from somewhere like XDA and flash it.

Answer (score 1):

Tread carefully here.  If your Galaxy Note 10.1 has the Knox bootloader (the 2014 edition does), then you won't be able to downgrade the OS even if you have a Nandroid backup or the original Jellybean firmware.  Knox prevents downgrades and you'll likely soft brick your device.  I did this accidentally on by Galaxy S4 by applying an older firmware backup (only a minor patch release) instead of the most current one.